# Mediawiki page slow to load on first access on apache server (AWS Ubuntu EC2)

Tags: apache-2.2, amazon-web-services, mediawiki

I have a mediawiki page running on apache server on a Ubuntu EC2 on AWS. On first access of the website, it takes >20s for Initial connection (inspected in Chrome), after that the page works normally, even if I close the browser and reopen the URL. But if I delete all internet history, it becomes slow again on first load.

In AWS I have an ELB pointing to Route53 DNS, when I checked the access log of apache, nothing came up when the page idling on first access, after that the log showed normal access.

I'm not an expert in this so I don't know what's the issue, is it from the server or from AWS?

Answer (score 0):

To see if it is because of your server, add %D to your apache's log config, that shows the time in microseconds for each logged HTTP request, for example:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D" profiling
CustomLog "/path/to/log/dir/access_log"
```

Then check your access_log for example, requests that took more than 5 seconds:

```
awk '{ if ($NF > 5000000) { print $0 } }' < /path/to/log/dir/access_log
```